# Constructor from Java to C#

Tags: c#

How can I write in C# this constructor from Java:

```
public class CasinoFAQPage extends CasinoBasePage {

    public CasinoFAQPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: See the docs about [instance constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx)

Comment: What "part" of the class/constructor is in question? Identifying this would make for a better question/title.

Answer (score 1):

C# equivalent of `super` keyword is [`base`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx). And we are using `:` instead of `extends`:

```
public class CasinoFAQPage : CasinoBasePage 
{
    public CasinoFAQPage(WebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {

    }
}
```

It means that,  the `driver` parameter will be passed to the parent class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `base` keyword you could pass the constructor's parameter called `driver` to the base class. The base class is the class that `CasinoFAQPage` inherits from.

```
public CasinoFAQPage(WebDriver driver) : base(driver) 
{

}
```

As it is stated more formally in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx):

> The base keyword is used to access members of the base class from
>   within a derived class: Call a method on the base class that has been
>   overridden by another method. Specify which base-class constructor
>   should be called when creating instances of the derived class.